# Разница двоеточия и тире

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире, двоеточие, запрос-ссылок

И у Розенталя, и у Лопатина говорится, что зачастую двоеточие в БСП (да и не только в БСП, практически повсеместно) можно заменить на тире без каких-либо на то причин, — вот можно, и все: такое, мол, часто встречается в публицистике и художественной литературе. Никаких условий, влияющих на выбор того или иного знака, ни в том ни в другом справочнике я не обнаружил.

Однако сдается мне, что они есть, и вполне конкретные, — просто не упомянуты. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно получить эту информацию?

Comment: Посмотрите ещё [у Валгиной](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-060.htm) (п.142).

Comment: Хороший ознакомительный материал можно найти у Валгиной http://yanko.lib.ru/books/language/ru/valgina.aktualnuye_ptobl_rus_punkt.2004.259_%28sl%29.htm  Это 2004 год,  прочитать его полезно, но я не ее поклонник. Это не самое современное понимание темы, интонационный принцип она недооценивает, а это не есть хорошо. Она дает очень общее понимание проблемы, элементы интонации  (длительность пауз, движение тона) она не рассматривает.